# JSON object inside data-attribute without using the quotes (for the Slick Slider data-slick attribute)

Tags: json, escaping, slick.js, custom-data-attribute

I'm working on a website where I want to add the settings of my [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) trough the data-attribute. This is possible with the 'data-slick' attribute. The format for this looks like this: `data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'`.

In my WordPress CMS I'm using the plugin '[Data Attributes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/attributes-for-blocks/)' to add data attributes to a Gutenberg Block. Trough this plugin all double and single quotes are converted to and therefor changes on the frontend to `data-slick="{&quot;slidesToShow&quot;: 4, &quot;slidesToScroll&quot;: 4}"`

This is not working. The Slick Slider doesn't use these settings.

Is there another way to add a JSON object into a data-attribute so it will work with the Slick Slider?

Thanks already for your help!

Kind Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I think storing a JSON value in HTML is a bad idea. There are too many conditions which you have to take into consideration - backend returning page, WEB server encoding (it can add a custom encoding header), and browser compatibility. For this task, I'd prefer 2 ways: bitwise mask or simple function-for example, define a few data attributes -data-s1, data-s2, data-sn. In the JS code, add an array [ data-s1, data-s2, data-sn]. And finally, add a loop with an in-condition (if data.contains(element of array) - read and then parse the data inside of the attribute). I never worked with wordpress but for JS it is a easy task. If you need example write comment below. I can update my answer

Comment: Thanks for your response Wusiki! But Slick Slider provides this method and for my use case it is very handy, so I would love to use it. But understand your point of view, thanks for your consideration!